# How to get authorization code for VKontakte in Java?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, vk

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        OAuthClientRequest  request = OAuthClientRequest
                .tokenLocation("http://api.vkontakte.ru/oauth/authorize")
                .setClientId("45XXXXXX")
                .setUsername("XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com")
                .setPassword("XXXXXXX")
                .setClientSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXX")
                .setGrantType(GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .setRedirectURI("http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html")
                .setScope("all")
                .buildBodyMessage();/** or buildHeaderMessage() or buildQueryMessage()*/
        OAuthClient oAuthClient = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());
        oAuthClient.accessToken(request);
        OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse tokenResponse = oAuthClient.accessToken(request, OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.class);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hi all, I am trying to upload some pictures and videos in my VKontakte app. When it runs, it throw following exception.

```
OAuthProblemException{error='unsupported_response_type', description='Invalid response! Response body is not application/json encoded', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}
at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthProblemException.error(OAuthProblemException.java:63)
at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.setBody(OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.java:70)
at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:56)
at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse.init(OAuthAccessTokenResponse.java:52)
at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponseFactory.createCustomResponse(OAuthClientResponseFactory.java:60)
at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:111)
at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:65)
at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:55)
at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:71)
at net.eha.VKTest.main(VKTest.java:39)
```

I spent too much time to find a solution, but I do not find a way. Please, any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I thought I would add this possible solution for future users and just in case I search for this in the future! I solved something similar a couple of weeks ago. The problem I believe is

OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse tokenResponse = oAuthClient.accessToken(request, OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.class);

Change this to:

GitHubTokenResponse tokenResponse = oAuthClient.accessToken(request, GitHubTokenResponse.class);

The facebook api gave me the same errors with oltu.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in a client/server system and I solved it by downgrading the Oltu libraries from version 1.0 to 0.31 , because other people had the same issue when upgrading.